# What is the easiest way to move work items from one project to another?

Tags: tfs

Moving source control files to another project is easy but what is the best way to move Work Items (with history) to another TeamSystem project?

I have a number of projects that I actually want consolidate into one TeamSystem project so we have one central Sharepoint portal and to make reporting easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh I used excel but lost the history. I found this link after

http://blogs.msdn.com/granth/archive/2008/06/26/how-to-move-work-items-between-team-projects.aspx

Good Luck